# Using python multiprocessing with multiple Large Language Models

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, large-language-model

I am using several LLMs (BERT, Word2Vec, & Alpa) to generate different outputs for each word in a text. Obviously, this is pretty slow - at least a second or two per word, which adds up very quickly for large texts. As a result, I'm trying to use multiprocessing to speed up this process by splitting the work between different threads.

My understanding is that multiprocessing is best applicable to situations where (a) there are a lot of tasks and (b) each task takes a non-trivial amount of time. Given that both of these principles are true in my case, multiprocessing seems like a good way to decrease running time.

The issue I'm running into is that pickling/unpickling my code is proving very computationally expensive. At present my code looks something like this:

```
import os
import torch

import gensim.downloader as vec_api
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertForMaskedLM, pipeline

from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count
import torch.multiprocessing
torch.multiprocessing.set_sharing_strategy('file_system')

vec_model = vec_api.load("fasttext-wiki-news-subwords-300")
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-large-uncased')
model = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained('bert-large-uncased', return_dict=True)
generator = pipeline('text-generation', model="facebook/opt-1.3b")

def pred_word(input):
  # make prediction with BERT using `model`
  # make prediction with Alpa using `generator`
  # get similarities of predictions to original word with Word2Vec using `vec_model`

if __name__ == "main":
  inputs = [] # array of inputs to pass to `pred_word`
  number_of_cores = int(os.getenv('SLURM_CPUS_PER_TASK', cpu_count()))
  chunksize, extra = divmod(len(inputs), 4 * number_of_cores)
  if extra:
    chunksize += 1
  outputs = None
  with Pool(number_of_cores) as pool:
    outputs = pool.map(pred_word, inputs, chunksize=chunksize)
```

Note: I'm using SLURM to run this program.

My intuition is that loading and/or pickling the LLMs in each thread is the reason this program is taking so long, even for very small input sizes. However, I don't really know a good way to get around this issue.